# What to do if the port is already taken by another application?

Tags: c#, port

I'm developing a server-client application. The server listens on some port (ex : 9090).

What to do if the computer is already using that port in another application? how do developers deal with it?

```
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9090);
server.Bind(ep);
server.Listen(100);
```

Comment: Choose a different port?

Comment: @Oded i would not be there when the user uses the application.

Comment: There is a range of numbers reserved for "well known" ports.  In addition, many TCP/IP stacks allow you to reserve a block of port numbers so that they are not available for automatic assignment.  You are responsible for ensuring that only one instance of your server is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You immediately terminate your program with an error message that says that the port is already in use.

That's what everyone else does, too.

(Of course the port number should be configurable.)

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) give up -- report error back to user/caller
2) use another port

The problem with 2) is that whoever is expecting to use your service will need to know the new port before they can access your service (and not the one running on the original, default port).

Answer (score 2):

The full answer would be that if the problem occurs, it's too late to do something except failing and complaining: the port is already occupied. Depending on local rules, you can invent some advanced policies e.g. to kill a task which occupied the port, but this can have weird consequences. The finally proper policy is to avoid possiblity of such situations.

The full port range (1-65535) is usually divided into some subranges. The range 1-1023 is traditional "privileged" range, so the port from it can be allocated only by superuser. This is traditionally strict policy on Unix systems but not on Windows. The range 49152-65535 is current IANA recommendation for automatic allocation when port number isn't explicitly specified - typical case is outgoing connection. But it is late standard. Current Linux by default defines 32768-61000 for this. Windows defined automatic range as 1024-65535 in versions AFAIK up to Vista, where it was reduced to IANA recommendation. So, previous versions likely have spontaneous conflicts for port number if a service is started not from the system startup. If you use modern OS, it's quite unlikely to get conflict with automatic allocation in range 1024-32767, but it's too high in upper range.

Another question is intentional allocation of the port used by your service. This can be avoided only using ACLs on port numbers and this is very OS specific. I guess there are such implementations for Windows but have never seen any. OTOH, IANA recommends that each software author registeres used port before really using it, so this helps to minimize chance to have conflicts with other software.

If you want to use non-registered but fixed port, try to avoid pretty numbers as 9090 because they are pretty not only for you:) Use random number generator and retry attempt until you get a number which isn't listed as registered.

Answer (score 0):

Make the port configurable.

This will allow the user to decide on another (available) port.

Answer (score 0):

Buy another box, assign it a new IP address and then run your app.

I see you are concerned about the user, how about telling them ahead of time which port it uses.   This assuming that your software can easily change the port for whatever reason.

A third solution would be to use a VM and a new OS instance.   I'm not a real fan of VMs so I won't champion this method even if it is the darling of the corporate world.  By the way VMs aren't bad unless you are the type that puts far to many critical corporate services on one machine and then shrug when the server crashes.